# Mapping, and autonomous drones

Tags: artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality, robotics

What is a good software to be able to navigate a drone in an augmented reality, is there anything that exists for individual and educational use in this area?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the platform to ask this question, but here is an answer. There were a few companies that tackled this issue in the past, dARwing was doing exactly that and edgybees did something similar. Both companies are no longer in this field.

Comment: That is very interesting and thank you so much for the response I will do some more research!